# How to automate excel pivot tables using python?

Tags: python, excel, automation, pivot

I have to periodically create the same pivot tables on excel but looking to automate the task using python

I tried looking for tutorials online but did not find any good and detailed ones

Comment: set the tables to look at a data set. Then use python to update the data in the data set as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example of how you can do it, modify it for your excel file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Sales', index=['Region'], columns=['Product'], aggfunc=sum)

with pd.ExcelWriter('pivot_table.xlsx') as writer:
    pivot_table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Pivot Table')
```